# If $a$ and $b$ are two roots of $x^4 + x^3 - 1 = 0$ prove that $ab$ is a root of $x^6 + x^4 + x^3 - x^2 - 1$.

Tags: polynomials

If $a$ and $b$ are two roots of $x^4 + x^3 - 1 = 0$ prove that $ab$ is a root of $x^6 + x^4 + x^3 - x^2 - 1$.

Students and I are unsure how to go about this problem. Also will this be a problem I can solve and prove in front of a class in 20 minutes?

Comment: Where did the problem come from?

Comment: Are $a,b$ just randomly selected among those 4 roots?

Comment: Not sure it helps or if I'm just pointing out the obvious, but since $a$ and $b$ are roots of the equation, we know $a^4+a^3=1$ and $b^4+b^3=1$.

Comment: I'm unsure where the problem comes from. Students bring me problems they are unsure of and we attempt to work them out.

Comment: **Note** $\ $ The statement is true only for *distinct* roots $\, a\ne b.\:$ The squares of the roots satisfy $\, x^4 - x^3 - 2 x^2 + 1 = 0.\ \ $

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I enjoyed tinkering around with it, and was pleased to learn that whenever $x^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has the roots $\{p,q,r\}$, then $x^3 -cx^2 +bdx-d^2$ has the roots $\{pq,qr,pr\}$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer USAMO https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1977_USAMO_Problems/Problem_3

Answer (score 11):

There is probably a shorter way, but I think this way sheds some light on why it's true:

Let $a,b,c,d$ be the four roots of $x^4+x^3-1$, so that $x^4+x^3-1=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$. Now set
$$
g(x) = (x-ab)(x-ac)(x-ad)(x-bc)(x-bd)(x-cd).
$$
This polynomial is symmetric in the roots $a,b,c,d$, and so its coefficients will be rational numbers (since the coefficients of $x^4+x^3-1$ are rational). This explains *why* there is such a sextic; to work out its coefficients, we need to mess around with symmetric polynomials.

The coefficients of the original polynomial tell us that $a+b+c+d=-1$, $abcd=-1$, and $ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=abc+abd+acd+bcd=0$. Therefore the coefficient of $x^5$ in $g(x)$ equals $0$; the coefficient of $x^4$ equals
$$
abac+abad+abbc+abbd+abcd+acad+acbc+acbd+accd+adbc+adbd+adcd+bcbd+bccd+bdcd = (a + b + c + d) (a b c + a b d + a c d + b c d) - abcd = 1;
$$
and so on - the coefficient of $x^0$ equals $(abcd)^3=-1$.

(One can play the same game with $f(x)=(x-a^2)(x-b^2)(x-c^2)(x-d^2)$ to obtain the polynomial $x^4−x^3−2x^2+1$.)

Comment: +1 IMHO this is the way to go. There may be some tricks helping us calculate the coefficients of the sextic, but manipulating the symmetric polynomials on the four roots is guaranteed to work, so :-)

Answer (score 8):

The [resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant)
$$h(z)=\text{Res}( \ \text{Res} ( \ z-xy, \ x^4+x^3-1, \ x), \ y^4+y^3-1, \ y)$$ 
is a $16^{th}$degree  polynomial in $z$ with roots $\{a_ia_j:i,j=1,2,3,4\}$, where $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ are the roots of $x^4+x^3-1$.

By expanding the above resultant we get that the polynomial $h(z)$ is [$$h(z)= \left( {z}^{4}-{z}^{3}-2\,{z}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {z}^{6}+{z}^{4}+{z}^{3}-{z}^{2}-1 \right)^2.$$](http://www1.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28resultant%28z-xy%2C+x%5E4%2Bx%5E3-1%2C+x%29%2Cy%5E4%2By%5E3-1%2Cy%29)

The roots of the polynomial $\left( {z}^{4}-{z}^{3}-2\,{z}^{2}+1 \right)$ are $a_i^2$ and the roots of $\left( {z}^{6}+{z}^{4}+{z}^{3}-{z}^{2}-1 \right)$ are $a_ia_j$ with $i<j$.

Answer (score 5):

The statement holds true only for *distinct* roots $\rm\, a\ne b.\:$ As such, the proof will require use of $\rm\, a\ne b,\:$ e.g. by cancelling $\rm\,a-b.\:$ Let $\rm\,f(x)\,$ be the quartic and let $\rm\,g(x)\,$ be the sectic. Then $\rm\,g(ab)\,$ can be reduced to $\,0\,$ by using $\rm\,\color{#C00}{f(a)} = 0 = \color{#C00}{f(b)}\ $ and $\rm\ \color{#C00}{h(a,b)} = \dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} =\, 0,\,$ namely

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} g(ab)\,\ &=&\ \rm (a^5\!+ a^4b+ a^3b^2\!+\!a^2 b^2\!+a^3\!+1)\ \color{#C00}{f(a)} \\
&&  \ +  \rm\  (a^6 b^2\!-\!a^6 b+a^6\!+a^4)\ \color{#C00}{f(b)}\\
 &&\ -\  \rm (a^6\!+a^4\!-\!a^3)\ \color{#C00}{ h(a,b)}\\
 &=&\ \ 0\quad\rm 
\end{eqnarray}$$

**Remark** $\ $ There may well be a simpler such expression (e.g. a symmetric one). I have not attempted to simplify it.

Comment: Is that guaranteed to work? I believe you, but I don't see it. +1 for a nice trick.

Comment: @Jyrki Yes, I know for sure that it works.

Comment: I would like to see the details.

Comment: @MJD I added the details.

Comment: Thanks. Cool! I was also wondering, whether you can **find** the minimum polynomial of $ab$ from knowing your $h(x,y)=(f(x)-f(y))/(x-y)$ and, of course $f(x)$.  Something like a suitable resultant may be? Not really relevant for the question at hand, though.

Comment: @Jyrki You don't need $\rm\,h\,$ for that. One can do a Grobner basis computation on the ideal $\rm\, I = (f(a),\,f(b),\,c-ab,\,d(a\!-\!b)-1),\,$ to compute the contraction $\rm\, I\cap \Bbb Q[c] = (g(c))\:$

Comment: By [insert a local deity]! That should work. Wish I could give you another upvote.